# How to know if user went through MFA during Google SSO

Tags: google-oauth, single-sign-on, google-signin, multi-factor-authentication, google-sso

I'm looking to implement [Sign In With Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview) for a web app and for compliance reasons, I need to ensure that the users signup/login to our app with MFA.

However, the users which are clients of our app, are not employees of our company, so I don't have access to their G suite accounts and cannot activate MFA directly on their accounts.

How can I know (or enforce) that a user went through MFA when signing in through Google SSO?

There are no references in above link and client libraries like [react-google-login](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview) don't mention anything either...

Many thanks!
Joel

Answer (score 0):

if you are using google workspace (gsuite), you can enable MFA as shown in this link:
https://mediatemple.net/community/products/googleapps/204404084/how-do-i-enable-2-step-verification-for-google-workspace

Comment: Thanks Alex for your answer - I may have described the problem in the wrong way. I do not have access to the G suite accounts of our users (they are clients with their own G suite account). I will update the answer.

Comment: are your users all using google accounts? Or you need to support other logins as well?

Comment: There is a mix; but so far we only want to support users with a Google account for SSO.

Answer (score 0):

There's currently no way for an OpenID relying party to determine whether MFA was used or not.

If you're using Identity-Aware-Proxy (IAP) instead (or on top) of OIDC, you could [configure a credential strength policy](https://cloud.google.com/access-context-manager/docs/create-credential-strength-policy), but I'm not sure if IAP is an option for your use case.

Comment: There is a way, but not all OpenID Connect providers support the standard. https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-modrna-authentication-1_0.html#rfc.section.5.1